# Is there a way to export and import the Amazon Connect - contact flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I checked there is a way to import and export the connect json in the Amazon Connect via UI.

[image]

It is working as expected. Is there a API (AWS SDK) available for importing? We want to automate this process! Could someone tell the way for achieving this?

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : I am not with Amazon Connect product team.

Looking through the  [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/connect/index.html) and [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/connect.html) docs, there is no API currently (i.e as of 03rd June, 2020) to support import and export of Amazon Connect - contact flow programmatically.

> most likely because this feature is still in beta status as per [Amazon Connect - Administrator guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/contact-flow-import-export.html)

Comment: I was about to write the same answer. There is also the general documentation on Connect API here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_ListContactFlows.html

Comment: @JayA.Little I too fed up for the same, Is there a cloudformation script for this import flow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159014/amazon-connect-and-cloudformation

Answer (score 1):

As of September 17, 2020, AWS now has an API for programmatically creating and managing contact flows: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/programmatically-manage-contact-flows-with-new-amazon-connect-apis/

There isn’t much documentation yet. https://github.com/aws-samples/ac-contactflowapi exists but most of the API functionality is buried inside JavaScript.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_CreateContactFlow.html probably describes it best. The content attribute is JSON serialized to a string and embedded again in the JSON attributes. I’m not yet certain where to find documentation for the JSON itself but you can build it interactively by using AWS Connect as shown in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this library I made: https://github.com/sethkor/connect-backup

It uses the newly released AWS Connect API, you can find details here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

It allows you to backup and restore contact flows plus some other AWS Connect components,

To back everything it can backup, including contact-flows type:

`connect-backup --profile your-aws-profile backup --instance your-connect-instance-id  --file path-to-write-backup`

There are options to also write to S3.

It also comes with a Lambda and a AWS SAM template to set up periodic backup too.