# Amazon Connect and CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-connect, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I found an interesting github link for automating the way to import the AWS connect flow from CloudFormation: https://github.com/iann0036/amazon-connect-cfn/blob/master/example_stack.yaml

It is working as expected. but this way is very complicated to frame the complete segment of connect flow in the cloudformation.yaml itself.

```
myConnectContactFlow:
        Type: "AWS::Connect::ContactFlow"
        Properties:
            ConnectInstance: !GetAtt myConnectInstance.Domain
            Name: "myFlow"
            Description: "An example flow"
            States:
              - Id: "play"
                Start: true
                Type: "PlayPrompt"
                Parameters:
                  - Name: "Text"
                    Value: "You have called an Amazon Connect instance"
                  - Name: "TextToSpeechType"
                    Value: "text"
                Branches:
                  - Destination: "disconnect"
                    Condition: "Success"
              - Id: "disconnect"
                Type: "Disconnect"
```

I am looking for a way to achieve the following:

1. where we export the Amazon connect flow from one instance
2. push the exported connect flow (json) to S3 bucket in another instance.
   (NOTE: Till this I have automated already, I am looking for the solution for following)
3. Now using the CloudFormation, import the connect flow (json) in S3 to the Amazon connect instance.

If there is a better way to achieve this welcome for your thoughts too.

Comment: if you could please share the directions you used to deploy this connect-cfn template it would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this: https://github.com/sethkor/connect-backup

It allows you to backup and restore contact flows.

It also comes with a Lambda and a AWS SAM template to set up periodic backup too.

It leverages the AWS Connect API released just recently.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has stated that they are providing APIs in the future to provide Contact Center continuous deployment.  They have stated that we are 2-3 quarters away from a complete solution (Public info).  Contact Flow, Queues, Phone Number, Routing Profiles.

You can get more information by asking your Amazon TAM.